# RoR: form_tag values to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am again stuck on my road to learn RoR, now with form_tag. I followed the rails guide but not able to pass the parameters from form_tag to controller. My index.html.erb is:

```
    <h1>Welcome to mySite.com</h1>
    <p></p>

    <p></p>

<%= form_tag(controller: "logins", method: "post") do %>
  <p>
    <%= label_tag(:username, "Username") %><br>
    <%= text_field_tag(:username) %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= label_tag(:password, "Password") %><br>
    <%= password_field_tag(:password) %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= submit_tag "create" %>
    <%= submit_tag "clicked" %> 
  </p>


<% end %>
```

## Controller looks like:

```
class LoginsController < ApplicationController
  def index

  end

 def create
   if params[:commit] == 'clicked'
     render action: "clicked"
   else
     render text params.inspect
   end

end
def clicked
  render text: params.inspect
end
end
```

## routes.rb

```
match "logins/index" => "logins#index", :as => :index , :via => [:get, :post]
#get "logins/create"
match "logins/create" => "logins#create", :as => :create ,:via => :get
#match "logins/clicked" => "logins#clicked", :as => :clicked, :via => [:get, :post]
get 'logins/clicked', to: 'logins#clicked'


#resources :logins
```

Button click on index.html.erb refreshes the page like brings me back to index page.

**Update:** Updated with the suggestions in the comment.

Thanks 
Abhi

Comment: The link_to's will not submit the form - they will just link away to a new page.  Is that what you want them to do? You don't have a submit tag for the form, which explains why it isn't being submitted.  This seems really confused, when you say "I read everywhere this is how its done" then you must have changed it quite a lot, or you've been reading something very weird.

Comment: I suggest you to read these [**Guides**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) before going further.

Comment: Actually, earlier I used submit_tag but that did not work for me. It was getting me back to the same page. I misinterpreted the link_to same as submit_tag.Thanks for that. Then how to attain that..my routes.rb : match "logins/index" => "logins#index", :as => :index , :via => [:get, :post] get 'logins/clicked', to: 'logins#clicked'. Am I going wrong somewhere here?

Comment: you should use button rather than links for 'submit' & 'register' because they 'submit' form and do not point/redirect to another url.

Answer (score 1):

```
<h1>Welcome to mySite.com</h1>
<p></p>

<%= form_tag(controller: "logins", action: "create") do %>
<p>
  <%= label_tag(:username, "Username") %><br>
  <%= text_field_tag(:username) %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= label_tag(:password, "Password") %><br>
  <%= password_field_tag(:password) %>
</p>

<p>
<%=submit_tag "Create"%> 
<%= submit_tag "Clicked" %> 
</p>


<% end %>
```

## Controller looks like:

```
class LoginsController < ApplicationController
def index

end

def create
 if params[:commit] == "Clicked"
  p "hi"
  redirect_to clicked_logins_path(request.parameters)
  else
  render text: params.inspect + "hi"
  end
end
def clicked


render text: params.inspect

end
end
```

in routes.rb

```
resources :logins do
 collection do
  get 'clicked'
 end
end
```

i hope it helps.

Comment: I made the changes from the above comment but the button click is getting me to the same page as if refreshing the index page. Yesterday also, I was stuck with it and now again. Can please someone show a working example of my problem described? It would really help me clear my doubts. Thanks again.

Comment: @user check it now hope it helps and it works fine in my local. if works replace render with your code.

Comment: make sure route is localhost:3000/users for your index page

Comment: I have updated my question with the suggestion provided by everyone..it doesnot seem to be working for me.. @santosh : Could you please post your routes.rb and other associated files once?

Comment: change your form_tag and routes.rb according to my answer

Answer (score 0):

you need to give submit path in your form_tag

## Welcome to mySite.com

```
<%= form_tag(clicked_login_path, method: "post" ) do %>
<p>
  <%= label_tag(:username, "Username") %><br>
  <%= text_field_tag(:username) %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= label_tag(:password, "Password") %><br>
  <%= password_field_tag(:password) %>
</p>

<p>

<%= submit_tag 'submit'%>    
</p>
```